# function sum multiple columns in sql

Tags: sql

```
`statistiques` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`pag_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`likes` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`comments` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`likepost` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`posts` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`talk` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`char` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`engagement` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT '0',
`created` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
```

and i have data in  table
i went to do this query for sum chemps in my table

```
select sum(likes) from statistiques where pag_id in (12,20) and created="2013-12-02"
```

but i went have multiple sum like

```
select sum(likes,posts) from statistiques where pag_id in (12,20) and created="2013-12-02"
```

but he isn't worked

English is not my native language, sorry for any mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is wrong. Try

```
select sum(likes), sum(posts) from ...
```